# Sum of numpy array based on other array

Tags: arrays, numpy, sum

I have two arrays:

```
array1 =    [[3,7,2],
             [1,4,5],
             [9,8,7]]

array2 =    [[0,1,0],
             [1,0,0],
             [1,0,1]]
```

I like to get `numpy.sum(array1)`, but only where `array2==0`

So in the end I like to have a value of 22 (3+2+4+5+8).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
array1 = numpy.array([[3,7,2],
                      [1,4,5],
                      [9,8,7]])

array2 = numpy.array([[0,1,0],
                      [1,0,0],
                      [1,0,1]])

result = numpy.sum(array1[array2==0])
print(result)
```

Output: `22`

You can index numpy arrays with other numpy arrays. Many operators, like `==`, can be applied as element-wise operations to numpy arrays.